# an error in integrating a function in R

Tags: r, debugging

The following code chunk is for defining and integrating a function f1 involving matrix exponentials.

```
library(expm)
Lambdahat=rbind(c(-0.57,0.21,0.36,0,0),
c(0,-7.02,7.02,0,0),
c(1,0,-37.02,29,7.02),
c(0.03,0,0,-0.25,0.22),
c(0,0,0,0,0));

B=rbind(c(-1,1,0,0,0),c(0,0,0,0,0),c(0,0,0,0,0),c(0,0,0,0,0),c(0,0,0,0,0))

f1<-function(tau1)
{
  A=(expm(Lambdahat*tau1)%*%B%*%expm(Lambdahat*(5-tau1))); 
  return(A[1,5]);
}

out=integrate(f1,lower=0,upper=5)#integration of f1
```

The integration in the above line gives the following error:

```
Error in integrate(f1, lower = 0, upper = 5) : 
evaluation of function gave a result of wrong length
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In Lambdahat * tau1 :
longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In Lambdahat * (t[i] - tau1) :
longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

To check for if the function outputs and inputs are of function f1 different length, 10 evenly spaced inputs and corresponding outputs of f1 are reported below. Input and output length for all the test cases were recorded as equal to 1.

```
sapply(X=seq(from=0,to=5,by=0.5),FUN=f1)
[1] 2.107718e-01 1.441219e-01 0.000000e+00 2.023337e+06 1.709569e+14
[6] 1.452972e+22 1.243012e+30 1.071096e+38 9.302178e+45 8.146598e+53
[11] 7.197606e+61
```

If anyone could share any hint or directions where the code may be going erroneous, it would be very helpful. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the function passed to `integrate` need to be vectorized, i.e. it should be able to receive a vector of input values and to return a vector of output values. I think `f1 <- Vectorize(f1)` could solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you so much, yes it got the problem solved. Thanks!